# How to start an external program from service

Tags: c++, windows, string, service

I am trying to invoke a binary from a service program. The path of the binary is fetched from a registry key. The path only contains "C" when I assign the buffer to the string. Where am I commiting the mistake. I am using visual studio 2010Here is the code:

```
std::string path;
getPathFromKey(path);
path = path+"\\myapp.exe";
argument = "start \"\" \""+path+"\"";
system(argument.c_str());
```

/*** retrieving key *****/

```
void getPathFromKey(std::string &path)
{
HKEY hKey = 0;
char buf[512];
DWORD dwType = 0;
DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(buf);


if( RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,L"SOFTWARE\\MYAPP\\MyApp",&hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    dwType = REG_SZ;
    if( RegQueryValueEx(hKey,L"InstallPath",0, &dwType, (LPBYTE)buf, &dwBufSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        for(int i=0;buf[i];i++)
            path[i]=buf[i];
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);

        return;
    }

}

else if( RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,L"Software\\Wow6432Node\\MYAPP\\MyApp",&hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    dwType = REG_SZ;
    if( RegQueryValueEx(hKey,L"InstallPath",0, &dwType, (BYTE*)buf, &dwBufSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        for(int i=0;buf[i];i++)
            path[i]=buf[i];
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        return;
    }

}

}
```

I get the following error:
**`Windows cannot find "C"`**

Comment: Seems to me your question is about how to load values from the registry, not about how to run programs, and not about services.

Comment: Have you looked in the registry with regedit and validated that the string value is what you are expecting?

Comment: @RobKennedy I still can't get it running properly

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. What is your question?

Comment: @RobKennedy I am getting a single character instead of a string.

Comment: That's not a question. I already knew that, which is why I voted to mark this question as a duplicate of a question that specifically deals with the problem of getting just one character from the registry. What's *new* in your case?

Answer (score 0):

If you get letter C, that means your code is partially working. However, this:

```
for(int i=0;buf[i];i++)
    path[i]=buf[i];
```

makes no sense, at least not for me, because I can't even image how this cycle would work (given that you get letter C probably means that it runs once). A simple solution would be to use this:

```
path = std::string(buf);
```

If I am wrong then check buf value before return, while debugging.

Comment: The loop is a C idiom, a more readable test would be `for(;buf[i] != '\0';)`

Comment: @Helix, I got it working by using RegQueryValueExA as RegQueryValueEx is replaced by RegQueryValueExW in Visual Studio due to Unicode.